# Spring Boot: Why am I not able to insert entry although I added the "NO_CONSTRAINT" attribute in the @JoinColumn annotation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, foreign-keys

I am trying to insert an entry into the "txt_auth_a" table which has auto_inc_id as the primary key and "account_id" as the foriegn key, thus there's a one-to-one relationship between account_id and auto_inc_id. The auto_inc_id is also the primary key for the "txt_account" table.

Text Account Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="txt_account")
public class TextAccount 
{
    
    //
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    //@Column(name="auto_inc_id" , nullable=false, updatable=false, insertable=false)
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="TextAuthA.class")
    @JoinColumn(name="auto_inc_id",nullable=false , foreignKey = @ForeignKey(value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
    private int auto_inc_id;
```

txt_auth_a entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="txt_auth_a")
public class TextAuthA 
{
    //
    
    //@JoinColumn(name="auto_inc_id",nullable=false , foreignKey = @ForeignKey(value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="auto_inc_id" , nullable=false)
    private int auto_inc_id;
    
    //@Column(name="account_id" , nullable=false)
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = TextAccount.class, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "auto_inc_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT), updatable=false, insertable=false)
    private int account_id;
```

The query I run in my DAO for txt_auth_a is:

```
@Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value="INSERT INTO txt_auth_a (account_id, username, email, password) VALUES(:accid , :username , :email , :password )",
            nativeQuery=true)
    public void signup(int accid, String username, String email, String password);
```

I am getting the an error of foriegn key constraint although I say @ForeignKey(value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT)

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`megamadz`.`txt_auth_a`, CONSTRAINT `txt_auth_a_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `txt_account` (`auto_inc_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: Why are you only referncing integers for id, is there a reason why arent you declaring the field types as `TextAuthA` and `TextAccount`?

Comment: ForeignKey only check on Hibernate side, but the exception was caused by database side. Check whether your database has constraint `txt_auth_a_ibfk_1`

Comment: @luanvu, I am able to insert once in the database by setting the foreign key constraint to 0. Why am I not able to to the same using Spring boot or otherwise what am I doing wrong while having those constraints above the 2 variables?

Comment: @PranavPatel "setting the foreign key constraint to 0", actually, you can do it by native query in JPA, but I don't think it is a good way. I recommend you to read about mapping and cascade in Hibernate. It's better way to resolve your problem.
[https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/),  
[https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/)